# Why will this not only return the string if it is a palindrome?

Tags: java

Below is the code that I wrote in order to have a user input a few different strings, check if each is a palindrome, and only return the palindrome. Currently, all of the entered in strings will be returned. It seems that the IF statement if not working correctly. Any suggestions on how to have the correct strings returned?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hh {

static void checkPalin ()   {
// creates a scanner
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = 0; 
String userInput = "";

// asks the user for the number of strings 
System.out.print("Enter the number of strings: ");

StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder(userInput);

StringBuilder palindrome = new StringBuilder();

// stores the number of strings user will enters
int stringNumber = input.nextInt();

// prompts the user to enter in their sentences 
System.out.println("Enter the strings:");

// this loop will go until the number of strings entered are entered
while(i <= stringNumber){

    userInput = input.nextLine();
    if(sentence.reverse().equals(sentence)){
    palindrome.insert(0, " " + userInput);
    }
        i ++;
}
// if( sentence == sentence.reverse()){
System.out.println("The palindromes are: " + palindrome);
}


public static void main(String[] args)  { 

    checkPalin();
}
}
```

Comment: you have to move StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder(userInput); in the loop. sentence is empty all the time

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `String` from the `StringBuilder` using the `toString` method before calling `equals`:

```
if(new StringBuilder(userInput).reverse().toString().equals(userInput)) { ... }
```

Comment: this works but would there be a way for it to ignore case and ignore the spaces too?

Comment: `if(new StringBuilder(userInput.toLowerCase().replaceAll("\\s+","")).reverse().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput))){ .... }` forgive me if there is mistake of brackets

Answer (score 1):

When you declare

> StringBuilder sentence = new StringBuilder(userInput);

The "sentence" variable will not change if userInput changes. You need to recreate the StringBuilder each time you need it.

Here is the fixed code :

```
static void checkPalin() {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    String userInput = "";

    System.out.print("Enter the number of strings: ");

    StringBuilder palindrome = new StringBuilder();
    int stringNumber = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the strings:");

    while (i <= stringNumber) {
        userInput = input.nextLine();
        String reversed = new StringBuilder(userInput).reverse().toString();
        if (reversed.equals(userInput)) {
            palindrome.insert(0, " " + userInput);
        }

        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("The palindromes are: " + palindrome);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write something like

```
new StringBuilder(sentence.toString()).reverse().equals(sentence)
```

in your if